# same settings and perspective in aptana for every project/workspace

Tags: ide, aptana, aptana3

Does somebody know, how to set up Aptana, to have only one *.metadata* setting for all projects? I don't want to change the default settings every time I start a new workspace!

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export the settings through the Preferences (`File -> Export -> Other -> Preferences`). Than, when you create a new workspace, import those settings through the `File->Import` wizard.

Comment: thx..too bad that this seems to be the only possibility to get that